# It's possible to use NuGet in a nexus oss repository?

Tags: nexus, nuget-package

I know that is possible use NuGet with the Nexus pro. I want to know if it is possible to use it with the oss version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NuGet support is part of the Nexus Professional features. The only way to use it with Nexus Open Source is if you write your own Nexus plugins that implement NuGet support anew. Although that seems like a waste of time and a very expensive exercise compared to getting a Nexus Professional license including support.

**Update December 2014:** As of September 2014 and the release of Nexus 2.9 the [full NuGet support is also part of Nexus OSS](http://blog.sonatype.com/2014/09/nexus-oss-meets-nuget/#.VJRa6sAAA). With the following releases of 2.10 and 2.11 we also added support for NPM and RubyGems.

Comment: Fortunately this is no longer true. Nexus OSS now supports NuGet!

Answer (score 2):

I think now ([from version 2.9](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-6738)) you can use NuGet also on oss version. 
[This comparison](http://www.sonatype.com/nexus/compare-repos) says the same.